# PHP Unset Specific Session by click

Tags: php

How to unset specific session in my code below:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION['src']);$i++)
{
?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $_SESSION['name'][$i]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $_SESSION['price'][$i]; ?></td>
    <td><a href="?delPrd=<?php echo $_SESSION['pid'][$i]; ?>">Hapus</a></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}

if($_GET['delPrd']);
{
    unset($_SESSION['name']);
    unset($_SESSION['price']);
}
```

Example I have 3 data with each session id. Now I want to unset session by click each delete link.

How can I do that? So I click delete then it will hide the row that I clicked before in `<tr>`

Comment: You will need to explain your question somewhat more clearly, please. I'm not understanding what you're trying to do, what you've already done and why `unset` doesn't solve your problem. Can yo define "specific session", you mean the whole session array?

Comment: Means, Im using add to cart session. I have 3 data in table, each row have delete link. So if I click delete link example in row 1 then it only unset session for row 1.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue when using the `unset()`, I tried to debug it to see if it would ever unset using a simple while loop.

```
while(isset($_SESSION['...'])):
    unset($_SESSION['...']);
endwhile;
```

This seems to work for me and actually unset the cache, it's like it needs to know its unset before continuing which makes no logical sense but that's code for you - you spend 50% of your time trying to fix code, the only 50% wondering how the hell it worked.

Hope this helped.

EDIT: You could make this into a reusable object, something like:

```
class SessionRemovale
{
    public function Remove($param)
    {
        while(isset($_SESSION[$param]))    {
            unset($_SESSION[$param]);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
$session_controller = new SessionRemovale();
$session_controller->Remove("....");
$session_controller->Remove("....");
```